# In the plane there are given vectors $a, b, c, d, $, the sum of which is equal to $0$. Prove the inequality!

Tags: inequality, vectors, geometric-inequalities

In the plane there are given vectors $a, b, c, d, $, the sum of which is equal to  $0$. Prove the inequality $$\mid a \mid+ \mid b \mid + \mid c \mid + \mid d \mid \geq \mid a+d \mid + \mid b+d \mid + \mid c+d \mid.$$

Solution: The right side of the inequality, like the left side, is symmetric with respect to $a, b, c$  and  $d$  (under the condition that their sum is equal to  $0$); since  $b+c= - \left(a+d\right)$ etc., it is equal to half the sum of the lengths of all pairwise sums of these vectors.

Given this, for the given  $4$ vectors with sum  $0$, we can choose the notation so that the polyline consisting of the vectors  $$\vec{AB}=a, \vec{BC}=b, \vec{CD }=c, \vec{DA}=d,$$ is self-intersecting. For this purpose, it is enough that the vectors  $a, b, c$, represented from one point  $O$, lie in the same half-plane, where  $a$  and  $c$  are on the same side from the line passing through the point  $O$  and parallel to  $b$. Then $$\mid a+d \mid + \mid c+d \mid=BD+AC \leq \mid b \mid + \mid d \mid,$$ and it remains to add $$\mid b+d\mid = \mid a+c \mid \leq \mid a \mid + \mid c \mid.$$

How can we explain this step $$BD+AC \leq \mid b \mid + \mid d \mid$$ in more detail? Since this inequality can be quite non-obvious..
Any hint would help a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since our vectors are parallel to some plane, we need to prove that:
$$|a|+|b|+|c|+|a+b+c|\geq|a+b|+|a+c|+|b+c|,$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are complex numbers and since $$|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|a+b+c|^2=|a+b|^2+|a+c|^2+|b+c|^2,$$ it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(|ab|+|c(a+b+c)|)\geq\sum_{cyc}|(a+c)(b+c)|,$$ which is true by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Why is the second step where you square all the terms correct? And how is it enough to prove the cyclic inequality?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon For any complex number $z$ we have $|z|^2=z\cdot\overline{z}.$ Also, use $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz)$, $(x+y+z+w)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+2(xy+xz+yz+xw+yw+zw)$ and $|z_1|+|z_2|\geq|z_1+z_2|$.